# Is there a class I should implement/extend for a game character in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I am making a side scrolling shooter platformer game using JavaFX. I am making an interface IEnemy that all enemy characters would implement. However, I was wondering if there was an interface or abstract provided by JavaFX that the concrete enemy classes should implement along with IEnemy.

Comment: Make sure that you extend `javafx.scene.Node` as it is the base class for scene graph nodes

Comment: While Node is the base class for all scenegraph components, extending something more concrete such as AnchorPane or StackPane might prove more beneficial for your purposes.